# helping in writing

Tags: writing

The telecommunications technology emerged to improve the rates and the level of people's communication as well as to exchange **ideas( people's idea)**. Due to/ through the misapplication and the overusing the telecommunications technology, many a family, however, suffer from **negative or adverse** effects of those.

First off, I am wondering which one of the bold parts or words are more proper?

In addition, would you please correct my writing, so that it could read more fluently or polished?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: nima, maybe you'll find [this question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/6700) helpful.

Comment: I am wondering the reason my question has not yet been answered, although it it about several hours that I raised it.

Comment: It's because questions about proofreading or requests to improve some writing are off-topic on ELL. ELL is for questions about some specific aspect of English or learning English. It's not a proofreading service or writer's aid. See the note above for web sites that provide that kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the better way to word this would be:

"...as well as to exchange **people's ideas**."

Also, I would rephrase last sentence to something like:

"Due to the misapplication and the **overuse of** telecommunications technology, many **families** suffer from negative effects."

Your use of the word "those" in that sentence is slightly redundant.  You haven't change the topic of the sentence, so you don't need to redirect the reader back to another topic.

Hope it helps!